# how to set class attribute with form_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following line of haml:

```
=form_tag :action => 'create', :controller => 'comments', :class => 'comment_form' do
```

But the html that gets output is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/comments?class=comment_form" method="post"></form>
```

I want to set the class.  How do I do this?

<-- Update -->

With this:

```
=form_tag ({ :action => 'create', :controller => 'comments' }, { :class => 'comment_form' }) do
```

I get this error:

```
 syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...', :controller => 'comments' }, { :class => 'comment_form' }...
```

<-- Second Update -->

The problem above is the space between 'form_tag' and '(' @woahdae's answer is correct

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) takes 2 options hashes, the first being passed to [url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for), the second being passed to the form builder.

So, you have to do it like:

```
= form_tag({:action => 'create',...}, {:class => 'comment_form'}) do
```

otherwise Rails thinks all the key/value pairs are for url_for, which will append any keys it doesn't understand as query parameters.

Comment: @Mischa figured it out. . the problem was the space between form_tag and the open parens

Comment: fremanoid and @gotqn, this is definitely, 100% the correct answer for the users question, where he wanted the url_for argument as a hash. As demonstrated in gamov's answer, the first argument can also be a string, ex that produced via a named route, in which case the second argument will be interpreted as a hash implicitly, and it will 'just work.' Trust me, this is right.

Comment: Yes @woahdae, I am agreed with you. Unfortunately, I am not able to change the vote - you need to make some edit of the answer.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
form_tag named_route, :method => :put, :class => 'disable_on_submit'
```

With Rails 3.0.15

Answer (score 8):

On Rails 5, you can do the following:

```
<%= form_tag(your_named_path, {class: 'form-inline'}) do %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do follow as:

```
form_tag your_path, method: :get, id: "your_id", class: "your_class" do 
end
```

Comment: This is incorrect. This will just add class=your_class to the URL parameters.

Answer (score -2):

In case you found this question and actually wanted to solve class naming for a [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for):

```
<%= form_for @task, html: {:class => "custom_class"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: form_for is different than form_tag.

Comment: @LaceCard And still, it's a better answer than the accepted.

Comment: @FellowStranger saved my time :)

Comment: In average I get one upvote and one downvote per week on this answer. Common, pour your negativity here so you can smile the rest of your day.